# How do i tell Scrapy to scrape a data-url that's in the start_urls instead of the urls themselves?

Tags: python, scrapy

So i just want Scrapy to scrape a dat-aurl that is found on inside of the urls themselves. This data-url to be specific.
Because the start_urls themselves only contain the partial list whereas the this dataurls contains everything that I need to scrape.

```
<div id="loadMoreShops" class="border-b border-grey-bright py-4 text-center cursor-pointer text-sm text-blue font-semibold underline" data-url="https://www.apomio.de/preisvergleich-zeige-alle-angebote/171865">
        Mehr Shops anzeigen
    </div>
```

My current code. It does scrape already but not just not everything that I want:

```
import scrapy, bs4, re, csv, logging
from datetime import datetime


class ApomioSpider(scrapy.Spider):

allowed_domains = ['https://www.apomio.de']
name = "apomio"


def start_requests(self):

    self.i = 0
    self.PZN_arr = []
    self.product_names = []

    with open('PZN.csv') as csv_file:
        reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
        headings = next(reader)  # to skip the header of the csv
        for elem in reader:
            self.PZN_arr.append(elem[1])
            self.product_names.append(elem[2])

    start_urls = ['https://www.apomio.de/suche?query=' + x for x in self.PZN_arr]
    for url in start_urls:
        yield scrapy.Request(url, self.parse)

def parse(self, response):

    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

    price_arr = []
    names_arr = []

    prices = soup.find_all("span", {"class": "block text-xs text-black font-medium"})
    names = soup.find_all("span", {"class": "w-5/6 block text-xs text-black-darker mb-2"})

    for name in names:
        name_res = bs4.BeautifulSoup(str(name)).find(text=True)
        temp = name_res.replace("\n", "").split(" ")
        new_list = []
        for elem in temp:
            if elem != '':
                new_list.append(elem)
        names_arr.append(" ".join(new_list))

    for price in prices:
        prices_regex = re.compile(r'(Gesamtkosten)([ ])([0-9]+)([,])([0-9]+)')
        result_price = ".".join(prices_regex.search(str(price)).group(3, 5))
        price_arr.append(float(result_price))

    if price_arr and names_arr:
        logging.info(f'Parsing prices of {self.product_names[self.i]}\n PZN: {self.PZN_arr[self.i]} on {datetime.now()}\n')
        self.i += 1
        for price, name in zip(price_arr, names_arr):
            shop = "Shop Name: " + name
            print(f"{shop.ljust(75, ' ')} Price: {price:.2f} €")

    else:
        logging.info(f'Item could not be found at {response.url}')
```

So the website that I have been scraping is called apomio.de, and I'm using the PZN (medical product identifier to scrape it). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

edit: so basically i want to scrape the data-url that's inside this element
[Pic of the Element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XoQO.jpg). The data url is in the code at the topmost of this post.

Comment: Maybe you can add images or explain it a bit better.

Comment: @Joaquin okay. will add images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to tell Scrapy to process you `start_urls` using different function:

```
def start_requests(self):

    self.i = 0
    self.PZN_arr = []
    self.product_names = []

    with open('PZN.csv') as csv_file:
        reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
        headings = next(reader)  # to skip the header of the csv
        for elem in reader:
            self.PZN_arr.append(elem[1])
            self.product_names.append(elem[2])

    start_urls = ['https://www.apomio.de/suche?query=' + x for x in self.PZN_arr]
    for url in start_urls:
        yield scrapy.Request(url, self.parse_start_urls)
```

And next you need to write parsing logic for your `data-urls` (I'm not sure what urls do you want to process here):

```
def parse_start_urls(self, response):
    for data_url in response.xpath('//*[@data-url]/@data-url').getall():
        yield scrapy.Request(url=data_url, callback=self.parse)
```

Comment: Okay, i think I'm almost there. I got the dataurl now (there's only one in the element). but the problem is it won't parse anymore.